# How to draw big circle (intersection of a plane with a sphere)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I use Geospacw to draw  two big circles but I cannot it using TikZ (or PSTricks).

[image: picture]

How can I draw it?

Comment: You should at least give it a try; this is not a "do it for me" forum.

Comment: @ Svend I want to try but I can not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just for typing exercise with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\newcommand\Orbit[2][0]{\rput{#1}{%
    \psellipse[linewidth=0,linestyle=none,fillstyle=vlines,hatchcolor=#2!20,hatchsep=2pt](0,0)(4,1)%
    \psellipticarc[linecolor=#2!50](0,0)(4,1){180}{360}}}

\begin{document}
\pspicture[dimen=m](-5,-5)(5,5)
\Orbit{red}\Orbit[300]{green}\pscircle[linecolor=blue]{4}
\pstGeonode{A}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note: `hatchstyle=dashed` does not exist.

Answer (score 7):

With `tikz`. May need some polishing but, I put it as such.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\newcommand{\greatcircle}[5][]{%
\path[#1,pattern=north west lines,pattern color=#1!60,rotate=#5,dashed] (#2) circle [x radius=#3, y radius=#4];
\begin{scope}[rotate=#5]
\clip (#3,0) rectangle ([xshift=-0.1,yshift=-0.1]-#3,-#4);
\draw[#1] (#2) circle [x radius=#3, y radius=#4];
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue](0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
  \greatcircle[green] {0,0} {2cm}{0.5cm}{-80}
  \greatcircle[red] {0,0} {2cm}{0.5cm}{-10} 
    \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1pt) node[xshift=5pt] {A}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @TheLastError No Golfed version :)

Comment: How to rotate the disc along another axis?

Comment: @rpapa not the rotation but simply change the `y radius`.